# What's the best hosting for ASP.NET MVC 2, Silverlight 4 and WPF with Team Foundation Server 2010?

Tags: asp.net, tfs, web-hosting

I need some web hosting for testing my internal web application with my few customers and hosting my personal public website. The web hosting must provide almost following request.

1. Allow me to use the following technology.

   - ASP.NET MVC 2 or higher
   - MS SQL 2008 R2
   - Silverlight 4 and WPF (xbml)
   - Team Foundation Server 2010
2. Price must not above $10 per month (pre-paid for1 or 2 year is ok if cost per month is not above $10).
3. Host should provide space greater than or equal 2 GB for TFS & web site.
4. Bandwidth per month should more than 10 GB.
5. Host should work well for my country (Thailand) and other zone.

PS. I'm not sure that TFS 2010 allow me to work via HTTP/HTTPS like I use SubVersion or not. Because I want to use it from anywhere even that place will block all uncommon port.

**Thanks for suggestion,**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182647/good-tfs-hosting-provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are freaking joking, or what?

> •ASP.NET MVC 2 or higher  •MS SQL 2008
>   R2 •Silverlight 4 and WPF (xbml)

Skip the Silverlight 4 and WPF part - this makes ZERO sense. Silverlight and WPF / xbml are client side technologies. Hosting has nothing to do with it, except providing MIME types, which are user configurable in any reputable host anyway.

> •Team Foundation Server 2010

Ok

> 2.Price must not above $10 per month (pre-paid for1 or 2 year is ok if cost
>   per month is not above $10).

Ah? **** (censired I*** word for not being politically correct).

Sorry. Did you look at the prices of TFS PER USER? No, your (unpaid) licenses are not transferable. The provier needs to use SPLA, or you need to proove your licensing (and even then - 10 USD per month for THAT monster - no way). Unlimited users heck, even 4-5) are not something that can be offered for that price per user by any logic. The license cost of TFS ALONE is higher than that, and TFS is not a low resource system

Your request is one of "living in a dream world". You won't find any business willing to pay for the priviledge of serving you. On top, proper TFS 2010 hosting also needs a lot of SQL and a Sharepoint site (for publishing documents and reports).

Let's see

Just as idea: VS Team Explorer Everywhere alone is 11,22 EUR (about 13 or so USD) per user per SPLA price list, which is provider purchase price. VS Team foundation user pricing is 19 USD per user per month - that is about 25 USD. Again, PER USER and PROVIDER LICENSE PURCHASE.

Any crazy ideas why he should offer you X users for 10 USD when he pays more PER USER just to get the license?

Some offers:

TFS Hhosting, like per http://www.praktikhosting.com/ - pack of 10: USD 65 (!) PER USER PER MONTH. That is for ONE user 6.5 times your wannabe offer.

Another one: http://www.teamdevcentral.com/hosted_Team_Foundation_Server_TFS_pricing.aspx,  down to 150 CAD per user per month.

Hm, when you find someone - I look for a guy to rent me a Ferrari, including fuel and insurance, unlimited km, but I only want to pay 500 USD per month. Tell me if you find one. Unrealsitic? Same level as your request.

Comment: I know both Silverlight & WPF are client-side technology but some hosting may not allow me to serve some file type include xap or xbml. But it shoule be a rare case for low cost hosting.

Comment: For TFS, I don't know its price before. Do you have any solution that much cheaper than that like SVN + issue tracker? It's ok if it natively supports VS2010.

Comment: I just see the following about very cheap starter price for TFS server + ASP.NET web hosting. But I cannot found exactly price about it on its website.

http://webhosting.asphostcentral.com/post/2010/04/28/Team-Foundation-Server-(TFS)-2010-Hosting-with-ASPHostCentralcom.aspx

Comment: Sou-Master - delosional? The prices I quoted are from the official hosting provider price list from Microsoft for this month. You expecct asphostcentral to undercut their own licensing cost? And yes, I know some alternatives. Open a slashdot topic if you don't know them. I prefer TFS these days, but i also have licenses and I self-host on my own servers.